# How to repeat captcha letters

Tags: javascript, audio, captcha, repeat

So, i have this captcha php code, that randomly generates a string and creates an image with it...
Now i am trying to do a system that will repeat the letters. I have used a speech synthetizer to create sounds for letters and numbers from 0-9 and a-z.
But my code is just overly complicated and it crashes firefox when i run it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/playAudio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listenString = "12";
var timeout = false;
var currentStringOrder = 0;
function play()
{
    if(currentStringOrder == 0)
    {
        if(listenString[0] == "1")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/1.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "2")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/2.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "3")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/3.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "4")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/4.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "5")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/5.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "6")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/6.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "7")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/7.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "8")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/8.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "9")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/9.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "A")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/a.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "B")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/b.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "C")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/c.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "D")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/d.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "E")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/e.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "F")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/f.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "G")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/g.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "H")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/h.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "I")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/i.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "J")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/j.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "K")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/k.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "L")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/l.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "M")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/m.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "N")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/n.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "O")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/o.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "P")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/p.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "Q")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/q.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "R")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/r.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "S")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/s.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "T")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/t.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "U")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/u.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "V")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/v.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "W")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/w.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "X")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/x.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "Y")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/y.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
        else if(listenString[0] == "Z")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/z.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 1;
        }
    }
    else if(currentStringOrder == 1)
    {
        if(listenString[1] == "1")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/1.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "2")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/2.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "3")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/3.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "4")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/4.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "5")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/5.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "6")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/6.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "7")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/7.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "8")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/8.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "9")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/9.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "A")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/a.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "B")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/b.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "C")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/c.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "D")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/d.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "E")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/e.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "F")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/f.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "G")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/g.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "H")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/h.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "I")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/i.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "J")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/j.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "K")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/k.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "L")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/l.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "M")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/m.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "N")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/n.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "O")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/o.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "P")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/p.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "Q")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/q.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "R")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/r.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "S")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/s.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "T")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/t.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "U")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/u.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "V")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/v.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "W")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/w.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "X")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/x.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "Y")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/y.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
        else if(listenString[1] == "Z")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/z.mp3");
            setTimeout(play(), 1000);
            currentStringOrder = 2;
        }
    }
    else if(currentStringOrder == 2)
    {
        if(listenString[2] == "1")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/1.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "2")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/2.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "3")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/3.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "4")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/4.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "5")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/5.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "6")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/6.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "7")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/7.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "8")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/8.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "9")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/9.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "A")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/a.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "B")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/b.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "C")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/c.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "D")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/d.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "E")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/e.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "F")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/f.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "G")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/g.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "H")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/h.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "I")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/i.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "J")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/j.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "K")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/k.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "L")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/l.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "M")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/m.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "N")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/n.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "O")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/o.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "P")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/p.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "Q")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/q.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "R")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/r.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "S")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/s.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "T")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/t.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "U")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/u.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "V")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/v.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "W")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/w.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "X")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/x.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "Y")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/y.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
        else if(listenString[2] == "Z")
        {
            playAudio(audioToPlay = "../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/z.mp3");
            currentStringOrder = 3;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: Instead of using over 100 if statements, you should probably use `for`-loops and store the URLs in an object. Using `currentStringOrder += 1` to increment by 1 means you don't need to check for the specific value of `currentStringOrder` as well.

Comment: Also, `playAudio(audioToPlay = "...");` --- `audioToPlay = ...` probably doesn't do what you think it does. (The statement is basically the same as `audioToPlay = ...; playAudio(audioToPlay);`.)

Comment: Finally, this is probably the reason why your program crashes: `setTimeout(play(), 1000);`. It's supposed to be `setTimeout(play, 1000);`, otherwise it will just call `play` immediately (infinitely, in fact).

Comment: Also for those of you who want to know how i do playAudio(). It's a script that i created that uses jQuery.

Comment: The script is:                                                                                                         `var audio = {};
function playAudio(audioToPlay)
{
 audio["sound"] = new Audio();
 audio["sound"].src = audioToPlay;
 audio["sound"].play();
}`

Comment: If `listenString` is the audio version of the captcha and javascript has access to it, doesn't that mean a bot can just use that to solve your captcha?

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I will just do it so instead of being called listenString i will just give it a random name with php rand() command.

Comment: i ended up using a custom method to generate a random string, because javascript variables can't be numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What likely causes your script to crash:

```
setTimeout(play(), 1000);
```

This statement *immediately*  calls `play()`, which immediately calls `play` again, etc., infinitely. The proper way to call `setTimeout` is:

```
setTimeout(play, 1000);
```

This will call `play` in 1000 ms, which is the expected behavior.

---

Other than this, you can drastically reduce your code by using objects, and doing something like this:

```
var urlList = {
  'A': '../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/a.mp3',
  'B': '../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/b.mp3',
  'C': '../scripts/captcha/soundtracks/c.mp3',
};

if(currentStringOrder == 0) {
  if(listenString[0] in urlList) {
    var url = urlList[listenString[0]];
    playAudio(url);
    setTimeout(play, 1000);
    currentStringOrder = 1;
  }
} else if(currentStringOrder == 1) {
  // ...
}
```